# Can't star large numbers (hundreds) of files in Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive

I tried to star 720 files in Google Drive (in the web UI). First of all it took forever (maybe 15 minutes) but when it was done, I got the usual notification in the lower left corner that the starring was done - but when I looked under `Starred` or searched for `is:starred` none of the files were starred.

How can I efficiently star (or tag them in some other way) large number of files i Google Drive? (I want to mark thousands of files at a time)